# Proving that a non-empty subset of a vector space is itself a subspace iff it satisfies the closure axioms

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I have a problem understanding a certain part in the proof. The proof goes as follows:-

### The proof :-

If S is a subspace then trivially by definition it satisfies the closure axioms.
Conversely, if S satisfies the closure axioms then the axioms 3,4,7,8,9,10 are trivially satisfied.

Axiom 5:- Let V be a linear space
$$S \subseteq V  \implies \exists O (\forall u \in S \implies u+O = u)$$ 
let $u$ be any element in $S$ , then by hypothesis  $ku \in S$ since it satisfies the closure axioms. Let $k$=0 then by a previous theorem which states as follows:- 
**In a given linear space , let $u$ and $v$ be any arbitrary vectors and k and d arbitrary scalars then we have the following properties** :- 
[1] $0u=O$ 
 [2] $cO = O$ 
......  
and since  $ku \in S$ then it follows that $O \in S$  from [1].
 The proof follows from here proving also that axiom 6 is true in the same sense.

### My problem :-

How can we apply the theorem that states $0u=O$ while that theorem only holds in a Linear Space while we haven't proved that $S$ is indeed a linear space.

Comment: Closure won't be enough for a general subset $\;S\subset V\;$ . You must *first* require $\;S\neq\emptyset\;$

Answer (score 1):

The key is that $S\subseteq V$, and $V$ **is** a linear space. As the property you mention is universal, i.e., holds for every element of $V$, then it is true for all elements in $S$.